# mocking serverletInputStream is never ending

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dropwizard

I have a following unit test which is taking too long to run and I am not sure why,:

```
class SomeClassTest{

private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

HttpServletRequest req = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
ServletInputStream inputStream = mock(ServletInputStream.class);

private SomeClass someclass;

@BeforeEach
    void setUp(){
        someclass = new SomeClass();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
    }

@Test
    void function() throws IOException {
        UserDefinedClass Entry = new UserDefinedClass(ConstantForTest.MOCK_OBJECT);
        String EntryJson =  MAPPER.writeValueAsString(Entry);
        when(req.getInputStream()).thenReturn(inputStream);
        LOGGER.info(EntryJson); // this gets printed
        when(IOUtils.toString(inputStream)).thenReturn(EntryJson); // it is stuck here
        Response EntryResponse = someclass.function(req);
        assertNotNull(EntryResponse);
        assertEquals(EntryResponse.getStatus(),Status.OK.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

I am NOT using springboot. Using dropwizard instead.

Comment: Don't mock the stream as an actual stream is needed. Unless you want to mock every single method of the mock stream (which I wouldn't recommend), You need to return a _real_ input stream instance.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha what is the proposed solution?

Comment: _"You need to return a real input stream"_- Me

Comment: You can use a [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)